# Simplexml get attributes with a namespace

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml

I have an XML Document which has attributes with a namespace. The XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.sunil.tweet"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.sunil.tweet.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

How can I extract the `android:name` attribute from the `activity` tag?

Comment: I have edited the question with the full xml file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the namespace when getting the attribute. The `android` namespace is defined as:

> http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android

So you need to pass that to the [`attributes()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) method, like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr);

echo (string) $xml->application->activity->attributes('http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android')->name;
```

**Outputs**

> com.sunil.tweet.MainActivity

[**Codepad Demo**](http://codepad.org/hpWdfH5S)