# PHP SimpleXML is missing attributes

Tags: php, xml

This isn't a dupe question.  Others are missing the attributes in print_r.
But I can't access the attribute xlink:href at all.

Here's what i've tried:

```
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($imageSVG);           
        $image = $xml->g->image; // works
        $style = $xml->g->image->style; // works
        $style = $xml->g->image['style']; // works
        $remoteHref = $xml->g->image['xlink:href']; // doesn't work
        $remoteHref = $xml->g->image['href']; // doesn't work
        $remoteHref = $xml->g->image->href; // doesn't work
        $array= $xml->g->image->attributes('xlink'); // 0 elements in the array
```

Here's the inputted XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="351" height="351" xml:space="preserve"><desc></desc><defs></defs><g transform="translate(145 175) scale(0.4 0.4)"><image xlink:href="http://cdn.katori.com/BfFEEXuBTrii818CNQvN_71344PL.jpg" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: ; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); opacity: 1;" transform="translate(-300 -300)" width="600" height="600" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image></g></svg>
```

Thanks!
-matt

Comment: This isn't a dupe? [there's bloody hundreds of them](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+simplexml+namespace) :P (But granted, if you don't know to add 'namespace' to your search it may be a bit tougher).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simplexml get attributes with a namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511217/simplexml-get-attributes-with-a-namespace)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `attributes` method requires the full namespace, not just the prefix:

```
$s = '...';

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($s);

$attributes = $xml->g->image->attributes('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
echo $attributes['href'];
```

Or use the second parameter of `attributes` (`is_prefix` - [boolean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php)) and specify the prefix only:

```
$attributes = $xml->g->image->attributes('xlink', true);
```

[Here it is in action.](http://codepad.org/1LrQ1n5Q)

Answer (score 1):

simplexml_load_string doesn't work very well with this-kind:of-tags

If you know the format of the xml that you want to parse and you need a quick dirty hack you can always for example do something like

`$imageSVG=str_replace(array('xlink:'),array('xlink-'),$imageSVG)`

or

`$imageSVG=str_replace(array('xlink:'),array(''),$imageSVG);`

before you

`simplexml_load_string($imageSVG);`

Hope it works for you