# Trouble with simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, simplexml

Trying to convert some xml into json and some attributes are not showing up that are using namespaces. The rest works fine.

```
        $xml  = simplexml_load_string($body);
        $json = json_encode($xml);
        return json_decode($json, true);
```

`stats-ice-hockey-offensive xts:goals="4" assists="7" goals-short-handed="0" power-play-amount="2" goals-power-play="1" goals-empty-net="0" xts:shots="25" />`

Any attribute that has xts: prefixed does not seem to show up. All others do. Any idea on how to allow that prefix to be picked up? Ive even tried str_replace to remove the `xts:`on the raw xml string but that seems to break the xml. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Using `json_encode`/`json_decode` is not a good way of doing this, it would be better to work with the original XML.

Comment: What would your solution be then to get this into a php array? The rest rest of the code relies on this.

Comment: Fetching attributes with a namespace is covered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511217/simplexml-get-attributes-with-a-namespace